# How to add custom stop words for lucene in azure search?

Tags: azure, search, lucene, full-text-search, analyzer

I know we can add custom stop words by adding custom analyzers. But I want to use lucene and only want to add stop words for that? How can I do that?

Comment: Can you share more details? What have you tried? Can you show your code? When you say *I want to use lucene*, why does that rule out creating a custom analyzer? One uses Lucene to create a custom analyzer. Do you want to add stop words to the *standard* analyzer, perhaps...?

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear. I want to add stop words to the standard analyzer in azure search.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of adding stop-words to the standard analyzer, using [Lucene.Net](http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/df/d8b/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_analysis_1_1_standard_1_1_standard_analyzer.html) (version 3.0.3):

```
using Lucene.Net.Util;
using Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard;

namespace LuceneDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var stopWords = new HashSet<string>
            {
                "foo",
                "bar"
            };
            var luceneVersion = Version.LUCENE_30; // v3.0.3
            var myAnalyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(luceneVersion, stopWords);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, for a longer list of words, stored in a file, or from some other external source, there are better ways to populate the set. This is just for illustration.